# Nautilus script - Bash script to extract current folder

Tags: bash, python, nautilus-script

I would like to use a Nautilus script that calls a Python script of mine, passing as a required argument the path of the current folder. This would avoid me the trouble of refactoring the Python script to extract the folder path from the URI provided by `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI`. Ideally, I would like to have something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
$current_folder=EXTRACT THE FOLDER PATH FROM NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI
python3  /path/to/my/file.py $current_folder -optarg 1
```

Where `$current_folder` is a required argument for my Python script, and `-optarg 1` indicates that my script also accepts optional arguments.

How do I extract the current folder with bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bash command `pwd` can do this for you! Use that in your script like so

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
python3  /path/to/my/file.py $(pwd) -optarg 1
```